# Cuda index map 3D Block, 2D Grid

Tags: cuda

I'm new to cuda; I have a 2D image (width, height) with 3 channels (colors).
What I want is to lunch a kernel that have **3D block** and **2D grid** like this

```
kernel_2D_3D<<<dim3(1,m,n), dim3(3,TILEy,TILEz)>>>(float *in, float *out)
```

I use *x* for colors, *y* for width and *z* for height. My question is:
How can I calculate the row and column of the image:

1. unsigned int Row = ?
2. unsigned int Col = ?

and the I use this function to calculate global unique index

```
__device__ int getGlobalIdx_2D_3D()
{
    int blockId = blockIdx.x+ blockIdx.y * gridDim.x; 

    int Idx = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z)
                 + (threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y))
                 + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x)
                 + threadIdx.x;

    return Idx;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using y for width and z for height, then the row and column of the image will be calculated like this inside the kernel:

```
unsigned int row = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
unsigned int col = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

The current channel would be equal to `threadIdx.x`.

Comment: Ok I think I can't confirm that this answer is true or not because after some reading I discover that I can't do it in my laptop //There is 1 device supporting CUDA
// Device 0 name: GeForce 9200M GS
// Computational Capabilities: 1.1
// Maximum global memory size: 536150016
// Maximum constant memory size: 65536
// Maximum shared memory size per block: 16384
// Maximum block dimensions: 512 x 512 x 64
// Maximum grid dimensions: 65535 x 65535 x **1**
// Warp size: 32

Comment: @ALMIStack... Sorry for misunderstanding. I have removed the incorrect assumption.

Comment: so grid.z = 1 and I need ((n+TILEz-1)/TILEz)